# Setting a timestamp throws PSQLException: Unsupported Types value: 2,013

Tags: java, postgresql, embedded-database

I'm using the latest Postgres version, but it still throws an Unsupported type exception if I call registerSQLType(paramName, Types.TIME_WITH_TIMEZONE). I can set stringtype=unspecified in the Spring configuration for the postgres data source and get around the issue by passing the parameter as an ISO formatted string.

However, I am trying to use EmbeddedPostgres (from [OpenTable Embedded PostgreSQL Component](https://github.com/opentable/otj-pg-embedded)) to write functional tests for my data access layer because the tests will be running in AWS without access to the RDS instance. And unfortunately the workaround doesn't work because EmbeddedPostgres chokes over setting stringtype.

```
EmbeddedPostgres.builder().setServerConfig("stringtype", "unspecified").start();
// throws FATAL:  unrecognized configuration parameter "stringtype"
```

Does anyone know a workaround for either of these two obstacles? Either a way to get Postgres to accept timestamps explicitly or to make EmbeddedPostgres take the stringtype parameter (which ought to be valid according to the [documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/83/connect.html)).

Thanks!

Comment: So what is the Java code throwing the error? And what is the SQL statement you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after a bit more banging my head against it, I found workarounds for both issues.  I'll post them here just in case anyone else runs into the same issues.

For the first problem:

```
parameters.registerSqlType(EVENT_DATE, Types.TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE);
//throws "PSQLException: Unsupported Types value: 2,013,"
```

I found that Postgres sets the value properly even when I set a straight Timestamp object, as long as I created it with the epoch time value.  So this works:

```
parameters.registerSqlType(EVENT_DATE, Types.TIMESTAMP);
java.sql.Timestamp sqlTS = new Timestamp(evt.getEventDate().toEpochMilli());
parameters.addValue(EVENT_DATE, sqlTS);
```

On the second issue--setting configuration parameters on EmbeddedPostgres, I realized that I was setting server config parameters, whereas what I needed was a Connection parameter.

Here's the code that didn't work:

```
EmbeddedPostgres pg = EmbeddedPostgres.builder().setServerConfig("stringtype", "unspecified").start();
// throws FATAL:  unrecognized configuration parameter "stringtype"
DataSource source = pg.getPostgresDatabase();
```

But this does work:

```
EmbeddedPostgres pg = EmbeddedPostgres.builder().start();
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("stringtype","unspecified");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(pg.getJdbcUrl("postgres", "postgres"), props);
DataSource source = new SingleConnectionDataSource(conn, false);
```

So if you need to set any of the postgres-specific connection parameters, you just need to roll your own DataSource.

Hope that helps someone!